# file upload using angularjs in php on button click

Tags: php, angularjs

the upload using the angular frontend (whichever way this is handled) sends the file data to a script on the server such as a php script (which is my preferred method). Once the php script has run I want to return to the page from which the upload was made and give a message there..I dont want the php page to display. Will appreciate some guidance on how to achieve this. Ideally what code to add to the php script. but i want upload procedure on button click or ng-click not "onFileSelect"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) directive, with many server side samples.

Follow here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/PHP-Example